# I am upgrading PHP 5.6 to 7.2 using fast cgi. After installation I am an getting internal server error

Tags: upgrade, php-5.6, windows-server-2016, php-7.2

I am upgrading PHP on a windows 2016 server but getting an internal server error on all PHP pages now. I went from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2 fast cgi non thread safe x86 version.  When I check in PHP Manager in IIS Manager all of the settings show the updated PHP files/locations

I am getting the following error: 'The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.'

Comment: You need to check the server logs to see what the actual error is. Internal server error can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: You mean the php_error.log? The php_error.log is coming up blank.

Comment: Anyone have an answer for this?

Comment: Very likely you forgot to install the Visual C++ runtime. Run PHP Diagnostics and it should tell https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi It was the Visual C++ runtime and my error logs permissions were messed up. I couldn't see errors and the error log having wrong permissions made PHP not load as well